# Posting an empty variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to NOT display the error message when you are posting an empty PHP variable? I'm doing an accepting and declining a reservation and in the form I have two check boxes:

```
echo "<form action='ConfirmAcceptance.php' method='post'>";
    while($check = mysql_fetch_array($pending)){    
?>
    <tr>
    <input name='approve[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $check['R_No']?>">
    '<input name='decline[]' type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $check['R_No']?>">
    <td><?php echo $check['ID_No']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['F_Name']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['L_Name']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['Req_Unit']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['Mob_No']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['E_mail']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['Ev_Name']?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $check['v_name']?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $check['Office_Approval_Status']?></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='comments[]' value=' '/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }

    echo"<input type='submit' value='Approve' class='Log'>";
    ?>

    </table>
```

here is the confirmacceptance.php where I post my contents:

```
$status="Approve";
$status2="Decline";
$reservation= $_POST['Approve'];
$decline=$_POST['decline'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
```

When I did not check a declined item it displays an error item because the POST variable is empty is there a way to NOT post the error message? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$reservation= isset($_POST['Approve']) ? $_POST['Approve'] : 'DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE';`

Comment: Hi @scragar when I tried this "Notice: Undefined index: Approve in C:\xampp\htdocs\Fac_Ven_sys\ConfirmAcceptance.php on line 38" still appeared. I copied that code above my variables.

Comment: in your code you have defined `name='approve[]'` and you are trying to get `$_POST['Approve']`  and second thing you have defined $_POST['approve'] as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use isset and a ternary operator to ensure the call isn't made if the argument isn't passed:

```
$reservation= isset($_POST['Approve']) ? $_POST['Approve'] : 'DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE';
```

If you're feeling lazy create a function to wrap the behaviour like this:

```
function p($arg, $default = '') {
    return isset($_POST[$arg]) ? $_POST[$arg] : $default;
}

$reservation = p('Approve', 'NOT PASSED');
$decline = p('decline');
```

Comment: Hey man this worked!! So if the decline is empty will I do this function also? but add 'NOT PASSED' in the decline part?

Comment: The second argument is a default, if you pass it in and the parameter wasn't passed into the page that's the value you get, if the param was passed in it overrides the default. The default is an empty string if you don't pass it in(which is a pretty reasonable guess for a default).

Answer (score 4):

Set `error_reporting(0);`

But it is better if you *Check* the variable using `isset($var)` before actually using it.

### Reference

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Turning errors off completely is overkill for this problem, and doing it like this raises issues of what happens when you get warnings in dev, skipping warnings is a bad idea, since it normally exists to let you know there are better approaches. Errors should always be turned off for live systems, so I don't think this will change anything there anyway.

Comment: Right @scragar. But Gaston specifically asked for turning off the errors. Anyways thanks for prompt response, I've updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

surely there is a way

you can do it like this

```
if(isset($_POST['Approve']) && !empty($_POST['Approve'])){
    $reservation= $_POST['Approve'];
}
```

Comment: isset() here is useless, as empty() encapsulates the isset() test. This can then be summed up as a ternary expression: $reservation = !empty( $_POST["Approve"] ) ? $_POST["Approve"] : NULL;